# Add leiningen.new.templates namespace as a dependency in project

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Is it feasible to add only [this one Leiningen namespace](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/new/templates.clj) as a dependency in a project (standard project and not lein template)?
I found this namespace is originated from [lein-newnew](https://github.com/Raynes/lein-newnew) (now deprecated) which means at one time this was possible.

I know that I could use whole [Leiningen](https://clojars.org/leiningen) as a dependency and refer only those namespaces that are needed but it doesn't look so optimal - whole Leiningen would be packed in uberjar and I need just few functions from a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to just import a namespace from a project (ex. from clojars, maven etc.). It would probably be quite a bit of trouble (think about dependencies, eventual configuration, the namespace may not even be part of the public api...).

So I would either :

- depend on the whole other project, fortunately in your case you can depend on `leiningen-core`
- copy-paste the code into your project (assuming the respective licences allow it of course). This has the added benefit that you will be able to modify it to suit your needs.

You can actually see an example of this "in the wild", in the [`boot-new`](https://github.com/seancorfield/boot-new/blob/master/src/leiningen/new/templates.clj) repository.

Comment: It does not make sense that every single namespace in every single project be available for separate install but leiningen.new.templates once was in a separate project, so in this case it make sense. Lastly, I think that mentioned namespace could be useful not only in lein templates but also in any project that needs Clojure code generation.

Comment: @foki for it to be available, it would have to be packaged separately (as was the case before).

Comment: I know, maybe it would be good decision to have left it separate.

Comment: Maybe, that being said there are probably alternatives to package several artifacts from a single repository (something like https://github.com/jcrossley3/lein-modules could help)